# Custom Flow deployment with custom site template

Tags: sharepoint, task, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a task list in custom site template. There is a flow attached to it. I need to create sites using custom site template and also want to ensure that flow is attached the newly created sites.

Environment is SharePoint Online and Modern sites are to be used.

Any suggestions would help.